# Use HttpWebRequest with async and await

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, async-await

I just started using C# so forgive my ignorance(if any) of how i use it.
I have a login button which executes the following code

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (email_box.Text != "" && password_box.Password != "") {
            string strRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +    @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +  @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
            Regex reg = new Regex(strRegex);
            if (reg.IsMatch(email_box.Text))
            {
                ApiCall request = new ApiCall();
                request.requestData = "{\"sessions\": {\"links\":{\"user\":{\"email\":\"" + email_box.Text + "\",\"password\":\"" + password_box.Password + "\" }}}}";
                request.requestMethod = Constants.httpMethods[0];
                request.resource_url = "/sessions";
                var response = request.initialize_request();       
                //Once i get the response string, i will deserialize it here and use it to do other things, like navigate to a new page an any other neccessary things to do!
            }
            else
            {
                recover.Text = "Please provide a valid email address.";
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            recover.Text = "Email and Password cannot be Empty";
        }
    }
```

The method initializese this class and also calls the **initialize_request()**, which inturn calls the **GetRequestStreamCallback** which also calls the **GetResponseStreamCallback**.

Intialize request is supposed to send back a string, which is set in **GetResponseStreamCallBack** but it seems, it sends back a string before the last two methods have executed.
Soo, i read about **async** and **await** and i have tried to use them, but the Visual Studio says **Cannot await "method group"** where i put the **awaits**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PrintMyPic.ApiJsonObjects;
using PrintMyPic;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace MyApp
{
    class ApiCall
    {
        public static string api_url = "http://myappsapiurl/api";
        public static string content_type = "application/vnd.api+json";
        public string requestData; 
        public string requestMethod; 
        public string resource_url; // the rest of the api url 
        public string requestResponse;               
    public async Task<string> initialize_request()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("the resource used is "+ resource_url);
        System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri(api_url+resource_url);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
        request.ContentType = content_type;
        request.Method = requestMethod;
        request.Accept = content_type;
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(await GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
        Debug.WriteLine("have we returned yet?");
       return requestResponse;
    }
    private async Task  GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("we are in the second method");
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = webrequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);           
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();
        webrequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback( await GetResponsetStreamCallback), webrequest);
    }

    private void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("we are in the third method");

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
            string responseString = "";
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            streamResponse.Close();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            requestResponse = responseString;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //show user-friendly error message as well as detailed one.
            //for better UI, consider using WPToolKit's CustomMessageBox to show these
            Debug.WriteLine("something wrong happened. \nDetails: " + e.HResult.ToString());
        }
    } 

}
}
```

Anyhelp fixing this is highly appreciated, i want **intialize_request()** to execute, wait for both **GetRequestStreamCallback** and **GetResponseStreamCallback** to finish, before returning the **requestResponse**

**[Update]** Based on the comments section, i have been advised to use **AutoResetEvent**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    class ApiCall
    {
        public static string api_url = "http://myappapirul/api";
        public static string content_type = "application/vnd.api+json";
        public string requestData; 
        public string requestMethod; 
        public string resource_url; // the rest of the api url 
        public string requestResponse;
        public static AutoResetEvent objAuto = new AutoResetEvent(false);       
    public string initialize_request()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("the resource used is "+ resource_url);
        System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri(api_url+resource_url);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
        request.ContentType = content_type;
        request.Method = requestMethod;
        request.Accept = content_type;
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
        objAuto.WaitOne();
        Debug.WriteLine("have we returned yet?");
        return requestResponse;

    }
    private void  GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("we are in the second method");
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = webrequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);           
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();
        webrequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), webrequest);

    }

    private void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("we are in the third method");

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);
            string responseString = "";
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            streamResponse.Close();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            requestResponse = responseString;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //show user-friendly error message as well as detailed one.
            //for better UI, consider using WPToolKit's CustomMessageBox to show these
            Debug.WriteLine("something wrong happened. \nDetails: " + e.HResult.ToString());
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("we are about to return to initialize_request");
        objAuto.Set();
    } 

}
}
```

Problem now is, **GetResponsetStreamCallback**  never starts, and it looks like i never return, because  `Debug.WriteLine("have we returned yet?");` never gets executed!

Comment: You do not need to have GetRequestStreamCallback method async. Change its signature to private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)

Comment: @VictorMukherjee i have tried, but still the 'Debug.WriteLine("have we returned yet?");' is executed before any of the two methods!

Comment: Also, you would want to use request.GetRequestStreamAsync if you want to use the asynchronous model.

Comment: Debug.WriteLine("have we returned yet?"); will execute before the two methods in most cases, because request.BeginGetRequestStream method is executed asynchronously, but since it does not use any async keyword, you cannot await the task. However, you can use an AutoResetEvent to wait the initialize_request method after BeginGetRequestStream and set the AutoResetEvent from GetResponsetStreamCallback.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee i have tried the AutoRestEvent, see updated question! thanks

Comment: @TheSammie: Consider using `HttpClient`; it's a *lot* easier for asynchronous work.

Answer (score 1):

Like Stephen Cleary mentioned and since you are building for Windows Phone 8 please consider using `HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest` class. The reasons behind this is not just that is "a lot easier".

As mentioned on VS forums:

> `HttpClient` is more like a head-less browser. It a powerfull and
>   ideal tool if you are going to be creating many http request. For
>   example you can set default headers and stuff. Here are the top 5 ways
>   it differs from an `HttpWebRequest`:
>
> 1. An `HttpClient` instance is the place to configure extensions, set
>      default headers, cancel outstanding requests and more.
> 2. You can issue as many requests as you like through a single `HttpClient` instance.
> 3. HttpClients are not tied to particular HTTP server or host; you can submit any HTTP request using the same `HttpClient` instance.
> 4. You can derive from `HttpClient` to create specialized clients for particular sites or patterns
> 5. `HttpClient` uses the new Task-oriented pattern for handling asynchronous requests making it dramatically easier to manage and
>      coordinate multiple outstanding requests.

For more information, please read the whole [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2ce80a71-1ced-4bcd-adb4-88eef6e6a42d/httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest?forum=wcf) and refer to this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/11/httpclient-is-here.aspx).

There are several examples and complete projects showing how to use `HttpClient` in different ways and not just to load string but to create c# objects from JSON objects as well.

Comment: I am going to look into `HttpClient` will give feedback on how that goes! Although, I would be more interested in a solution that fixes my current situation, and then alternatives after.

Comment: I completely understand what you mean, it just didn't feel right to me to use something thats obsolete. check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190216%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have turned to `HttpClient`, which is doing the job,  after several failed attempts to fix the problem, will push code to git-hub and share link here. Thank you for the recommendation